# hide data types in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, database

I am currently working on mysql workbench for my database project. I do not want to see data types next to the table items in entities. Is there any way to hide them ?

Also is there any complex database example available from design phase to working database to help me to understand the database making process ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a good resource for asking questions about *code*, but isn't a suitable forum for asking for general advice or support with a product like MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 15):

-- @MySQL WorkBench 6.2

1. Go to: Model > Model options > Diagram
2. Uncheck "use defaults from from global settings"
3. In the "Tables" section, uncheck "Show Column Types" and that's it.